# Proxychains "core dumped due to Bad file descriptor"

Tags: security, tor, proxychains

I'm currently learning to use Tor and proxies. I run ArchLinux. I have installed proxychains, but when I run "proxychains <target_browser> " command, the core gets dumped.

My proxychain is configured for a dynamic chain and I am using a list of 4 socks4 proxies. I expected the command "proxychains <target_browser> " to launch the brower, but the core gets dumped due to "Bad file descriptor".

This is the command I ran: `proxychains google-chrome-beta dnsleaktest.com`
This is the error I got:

```
[proxychains] config file found: /etc/proxychains.conf
[proxychains] preloading /usr/lib/libproxychains4.so
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[0524/225643.977083:WARNING:close_multiple.cc(66)] close: Bad file descriptor (9)
[0524/225643.977132:WARNING:close_multiple.cc(66)] close: Bad file descriptor (9)
[0524/225643.977134:WARNING:close_multiple.cc(66)] close: Bad file descriptor (9)
[0524/225643.977137:WARNING:close_multiple.cc(66)] close: Bad file descriptor (9)
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with google-chrome-stable! I would recommend installing either Midori or Firefox, as I had better luck with those.